# how find the index of multiple elements in the same array

Tags: javascript

```
let secretMessage = ['Learning', 'is', 'not', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'get', 'easily', 'the', 'first', 'time,', 'it', 'is', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'figure', 'out.', '-2015,', 'Chris', 'Pine,', 'Learn', 'JavaScript'];
console.log(secretMessage.indexOf('get','easily')
```

Why does it only log the value of the 'get', not of both 'get' and 'easily', and how can I return both?

Appreciate the help, I am a beginner, sorry if the formatting is bad.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: The second argument to [].indexOf is a starting index for the search, not another value.

Answer (score 4):

You can map `indexOf` over the list of values whose indices are wanted:

```js
let secretMessage = ['Learning', 'is', 'not', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'get', 'easily', 'the', 'first', 'time,', 'it', 'is', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'figure', 'out.', '-2015,', 'Chris', 'Pine,', 'Learn', 'JavaScript'];

console.log(['get', 'easily'].map(x => secretMessage.indexOf(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.indexOf()` function syntax is as follows `indexOf(searchElement, fromIndex)` so what that means in your case is its searching for "get" starting from "easily" in the array.

To search both you can try this

```
console.log(secretMessage.indexOf('get'));
console.log(secretMessage.indexOf('easily'));
```

and if you need them together you can assign each to a variable then display them together later something like this

```
let one = secretMessage.indexOf('get');
let two = secretMessage.indexOf('easily');

let result = one + "," + two 

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` is a [JavaScript array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#parameters) that only can look for one element at a time, whatever value is being searched for in the array.

A more flexible array method for returning the indices of what you're looking for would be [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which lets you return whatever value you want after iterating, including another array with the indices of the values that match your search.

```
let secretMessage = ['Learning', 'is', 'not', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'get', 'easily', 'the', 'first', 'time,', 'it', 'is', 'about', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'figure', 'out.', '-2015,', 'Chris', 'Pine,', 'Learn', 'JavaScript'];

const matchingIndices = secretMessage.reduce((results, currentValue, currentIndex)=> {
  if (currentValue === 'get' || currentValue === 'easily'){
    results.push(currentIndex)
  }

  return results;
}, [])

console.log(matchingIndices) // => [6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) MDN Web Docs,

"The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present."

The optional use of the second parameter is to set a starting point for that search:

**Example:** indexOf(searchElement, fromIndex)

**Parameter 1:** *searchElement*

- Element to locate in the array.

**Parameter 2 (Optional):** *fromIndex*

- The index to start the search at. If the index is greater than or equal to the array's length, -1 is returned, which means the array will not be searched. If the provided index value is a negative number, it is taken as the offset from the end of the array. Note: if the provided index is negative, the array is still searched from front to back. If the provided index is 0, then the whole array will be searched. Default: 0 (entire array is searched).